# How does ng-required interprete expressions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

There are lot of examples out there that show how ng-required can interprete expressions. Looking at the code in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/validators.js I don't see any code interpreting the expression passed to the ng-required directive. It just sets the required attribute to true/false. So how does ng-required work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot find any hints in the `requiredDirective` due to the fact that the attributes object contains special instructions for Angular properties. These properties will be automatically evaluated and set under a different name on the attributes object, e.g. `ngRequired` will be evaluated to `required` [1].

A list of these properties is defined in the Angular-bundled `jqLite` version [2]. Also see the list of Angular directives as evidence that `ngRequired` and `required` actually have the same implementation [3].

[1] https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/6b123a0419d6cd2009f148e2f1c6be3b5465373f/src/ng/directive/attrs.js#L366

[2] https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/cdd1227a308edd34d31b67f338083b6e0c4c0db9/src/jqLite.js#L535-L538

[3] https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/7dcfe5e03ee0943f92791a0e066ce42636ab1b58/src/AngularPublic.js#L202-L203